# Is wso2ei integrator stateless ? (in a cluster context)

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I set up a wso2ei integrator cluster by WKA, by following this guide [Clustering the ESB Profile](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI630/Clustering+the+ESB+Profile).

From my understanding of ESB, all transactions are stateless. For scalability issue in containers I would rather make a cluster without this configuration, is it a state achievable ? A cluster of wso2 integrator where each component doesn't know the others

Thank you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a specific programming problem but rather a request for explanation and examples.

Comment: you are right, thank you for pointing this out. I edited my question to be more precise, do you confirm your impression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A cluster of wso2 integrator where each component doesn't know the others

What the cluster is used for

- cache invalidation
- registry database
- synchronization of artifact deployments
- synchronization of tasks (scheduled tasks, message processor, ..)

if you don't use any of these and you just use basic stateless components (such as proxies, esb apis, ..) and you can deploy the same artifacts to all servers, you may be ok to go even without the hazelcast (wka) cluster